# Issue making form work with AJAX

Tags: javascript, ajax, forms

I've created a form on a clients site and I'm trying to use AJAX for the subscribe form.

The submit seems to just redirect rather than serializing the form and working with AJAX.

I think the issue here is that it doesn't know whether the response data is "success" or not.. possibly utilises a different variable to determine if it was a success or error? It should display the message accordingly to the user either way, ie:

Success -> You have been signed up.
Error -> Invalid email address.

Should also be a message for a blank name entered as it's a required field but unsure how to handle that error.. :/

**Complete Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/pUd5P/6/

**Form**

```
<form id="newsletter" action="http://app.bronto.com/public/webform/process/" method="post">
....
</form>
```

**JS**

```
//ajax subscribe
$( document ).ready( function() {
     $("#newsletter").submit( function() {
        //Do the AJAX post
        //alert("submitting");
        alert(data);
        $.post($("#newsletter").attr("action"), 
        $("#newsletter").serialize(), 
        function( data ) {
            //alert(data);
            if ( data == 'success' ) {
                $('#newsletter-message').html('You have been signed up.')
                             .removeClass('error')
                             .css('visibility','visible');
            } else {
                $('#field-error').html('Invalid email address.')
                                 .addClass('error')
                                 .css('visibility','visible');
            }
        });
        //Stop the normal POST
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: Have you included the jQuery properly? your fiddle is missing jQuery...

Comment: It's included on the site, however, I have edited the fiddle above that includes jQuery. Still no luck.

Comment: What is the URL that you have in the `action` field? This is the URL it is following. If you want to make an AJAX call, you don't need to add any action.

Comment: I'm using AJAX to serialize the form so it should post to the action URL and return a response, without leaving the page.

Comment: Just curious: how did you end up subscribing people in your case?

Answer (score 0):

have a look at [`event.preventDefault()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/)

```
$("#newsletter").submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    // rest of your code here.
```

This will prevent the form from submitting in the standard way and refreshing the page and allow your `$.post` to return results.

I can see you used `return false` but try this instead (or aswell as) :D

Comment: Tried but still no luck. Seems to not even bring up the alert with "data" :/ http://jsfiddle.net/pUd5P/9/. Feel free to play with the Fiddle to get it working

Answer (score 0):

I just dont understand this behavior but make it work

http://jsfiddle.net/pUd5P/12/

it is creating the problem on `name = sid` so i just changed it to tsid

`<input type="hidden" name="tsid" value="37ea72cebcc05140e157208f6435c81b" />`

now its making an ajax request, You need to test it on your server as it is giving 
`Origin is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.` error.

Comment: Thanks but still can't get it working. Can you add it to the jsfiddle to see? Otherwise check the latest update here with your answer implemented: http://jsfiddle.net/pUd5P/10/

Comment: @DT.DTDG hey check this new fiddle there.

Comment: it wont work on jsFiddle because its attempting to post a form using ajax to another website all together have a look at this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP/Access_control_CORS